# Login to Wordpress site via JWT obtained by third-party server

Tags: php, wordpress, jwt

I run a custom-made sales system built in php/javascript. One of my customers have asked me to create a system where users can login to the member area of his Wordpress site via my sales system. I.e. if they are logged in to my system and have the proper rights, they should be able to login to the member area of the Wordpress site via a link in my system.

The member area is common to all members, so there's no need to identify the user by name on the Wordpress site. For simplicity, I thought I would just create a Wordpress user called something like Mr. Member, and have my sales system server login as that user.

But after that I need to "hand over" the session from my sales system server to the client, so that he can communicate with the Wordpress site directly. How can I do this in an easy yet secure way?

My first thought was to install this Wordpress extension https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/ to allow for JWT's in Wordpress. When my sales server receives the token after login, I wanted to hand that token to the client as a cookie to use in his requests to the Wordpress site. But before I start coding this, I just want to make sure if this is a good approach?

Comment: I think it's good idea to use JWT. But you might use `localstorage` for token.

Comment: @Dmitry thanks. I've never used localstorage, I'll read up on it.